# Passing the argument of an action in link_to rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have got an action which takes in an argument it goes like this :-

```
def join_as_student(course)
        @course = course
        .........

    end
```

I have a route for this :-

```
resources :courses do
    member do
      get :join_as_student
    end
  end
```

I want to go to this route by clicking on the route like this :-

```
link_to "Join",join_as_student_course_path(:course => @course)
```

However this gives me error `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` in join_as_student action

How do I pass the argument of this action in the link_to ??

**Update**

Full stack of error : -

```
app/controllers/courses_controller.rb:23:in `join_as_student'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__26464250__process_action__701751343__callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:201:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.1.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:145:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532:in `call'
omniauth (1.0.3) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:168:in `call!'
omniauth (1.0.3) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:148:in `call'
sass (3.1.15) lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call'
client_side_validations (3.1.4) lib/client_side_validations/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:247:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:331:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:477:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.1.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.1.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:456:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.1.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread
```

'

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I missed. You can't pass params for action. use

```
link_to "Join",join_as_student_course_path(@course)
```

and

```
def join_as_student
    @course = Course.find params[:id]
    .........

end
```

Comment: I am using join_as_student elsewhere as well where course.id is not available because of which I have to pass an argument here

Comment: I was doing it earlier like you have mentioned above but since I required it to have an argument I changed it

Comment: you may incapsulate this logic for example in find_course method
def join_as_student
    @course = find_course
    .........

end

Anyway, you can't pass arguments to action

Comment: I think if you're using the join_as_student elsewhere (where course.id) isn't available, then you're going about this the wrong way. Try to stick to restful routing that makes sense. Sometimes you just have to step back a moment and rethink what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 link_to "Join",join_as_student_course_path(@course)
```

Comment: link_to "Join",join_as_student_course_path(:id => @course.id)

Comment: run rake routes | grep join_as_student, you should see how something like: join_as_student_course GET    /course/:id/join_as_student(.:format)        
:id - parameter name you should use as hash in ..._path

Comment: join_as_student_course GET    /courses/:id/join_as_student(.:format)  {:action=>"join_as_student", :controller=>"courses"} this is what I get